# Catalan numbers from matchings?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory, catalan-numbers

There are several examples of interpreting the Catalan numbers as non-nesting or non-crossing matchings of some graph.
My question is:
Is there a family of graphs $G_1,G_2,\dotsc$ with the number of vertices
growing linearly, such that the number of matchings (not complete matchings)
of $G_i$ is the $i$th Catalan number?

I have checked Richard Stanley's book on Catalan numbers, but such an interpretation is not there. The closest I found is a family of graphs, where one counts the number of *complete* matchings,
but this is not what I am after.

Edit: I thought that the linearity condition was sufficient to force nice answers, but perhaps not. Ok so there is the classical recursion for Catalan numbers, $$C_{n+1} = \sum_k C_k C_{n-k}.$$
The family of graphs should be defined such that the number of matchings is seen to satisfy the above recursion without too much work.

Comment: Write the $n$th Catalan number as $C_n = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k$ where the $p_i$'s are prime numbers.  Define $G_n$ to be the disjoint union of $k$ star graphs, where the $j$th star graph has $p_j$ vertices. Then it is easy to see that the number of matchings of $G_i$ is $C_n$ (we can choose at most one edge from each star graph, and the $j$th star graph has $p_j-1$ edges). Since Catalan numbers have a nice product formula, all the $p_j$ will be $\leq 2n$; thus, I'm not sure if this $G_n$ has linear in $n$ number of vertices, but its number of vertices will not be huge.

Comment: @SamHopkins Ok, so there is another condition; the family of graphs should be 'appealing' in a combinatorial sense. That is, it should have been included in Stanley's book.

Comment: Yes, this is a cheating answer, which is why I left it as a comment.

Comment: what are the graphs for perfect (=complete, yes?) matchings?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: you can convert the usual Dyck path interpretation of Catalan numbers to perfect matchings in a certain graph made out of hexagons, in the usual way. See e.g. "Perfect Matchings, Catalan Numbers, and Pascal's Triangle" by Došlić (https://www.jstor.org/stable/27643031). But I think this graph will have a quadratic number of vertices, not linear.

Comment: @SamHopkins thank you! By the way, your graph certainly has superlinear number of vertices, since all prime between $n+2$ and $2n$ divide $C_n$, and there are many of them.

Comment: @SamHopkins Ah, yes, ok quadratic for the complete matching case, it is figure 2 in Stanleys .pdf: https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/catadd.pdf