# Counting matchings and perfect matchings

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

A **matching** in a graph is a subset of the edges such that
no two edges share a vertex. A **perfect matching** is a matching where every vertex is part of exactly one edge in the matching.

Counting the total number of matchings in a general graph is #P-complete (i.e. hard).
Also, counting the total number of perfect matchings is also #P-complete.

We know that matchings can be translated into independence sets,
so every matching counting problem can be made into a counting independence sets in a related graph. (But the converse is not true, independence sets are more general).

**Question:** Given a graph $G$, can we find (in some efficient manner) a graph $G'$
such that the number of matchings of $G$ is the same as the number of perfect matchings in $G'$?

**Question 2:** If the answer is no for general graphs, what about bipartite graphs?

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as (well, more general than) your previous question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443258/catalan-numbers-from-matchings ?

Comment: Sorry, I understand now that this question is about going in the *opposite* direction, compared to your last question: from total matchings to perfect matchings.

Comment: @SamHopkins Right, these are related questions - I was hoping perhaps maybe there was some complexity theory distinction. 
So finding a matching is trivial; take no edges. But finding a perfect matching is harder (but can be done in polynomial time, e.g. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62526/complexity-of-finding-a-perfect-matching-in-directed-graphs ) so finding G' from G in polynomial time is still ok.

Comment: Definitions? Please.